# Load external dll in Qt in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, dll

Assume, I have a folder with my program and also another folder with external library.

```
bin
    myprog.exe
etc
    lib.dll
    sublib.dll
```

In my case I want to load  the `lib.dll` from  my main program `myprog.exe`. The problem is that `lib.dll` linked with `sublib.dll`.

So I try to do that in this way:

```
QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
QLibrary lib;
QString path = "C:/etc/lib.dll";
a.addLibraryPath(path);

if(QLibrary::isLibrary(path)) {
    lib.setFileName(path);
    lib.load();
    if(lib.isLoaded())
        qDebug() << "Ok\n";
    else
        qDebug() << "Error " << lib.errorString() << "\n";
} else
    qDebug() << "Not a library\n";
return a.exec();
```

After running the app I get the error:

> cannot load library lib.dll the specified module could not be found

If I put both `lib.dll` and `sublib.dll` inside `bin` directory it works without error. But that is not I want to do.

I've tried

```
a.addLibraryPath("C:/etc");
```

but that doesn't work.
As I understand `QCoreApplication::addLibraryPath()` sets path for Qt program, not as system wide setting. So, in this case, `lib.dll` still can't find `sublib.dll` although it locates in same directory.

So my question - how can I load external shared library inside Qt program in case that this library has its own dependencies?

Comment: Are you sure that that lib.dll given correct EXE will load sublib.dll anyway?

Comment: Yes, if I put both dlls inside `c:/bin` or `C:/Windows/System32` it works fine.

Comment: The only safe way to escape Windows dll hell is to copy the dll's and their dependences into the application dir. Disk space is cheap. The sure way to suffer from the hell is to dump them in the system32 dir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is Windows issue. The DLL will be looked at the current process directory and then in the system PATH. The code that is contained in some `C:\etc\lib.dll` is behaving in its own process and unless very specific logic implemented will behave according to the system rule.

Please refer to MSDN article [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx#search_order_for_desktop_applications) for details. If the source code for that lib.dll is available, it makes sense to examine [LoadLibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx) call. If there is no specific path provided then:

> The first directory searched is the directory containing the image
>   file used to create the calling process (for more information, see the
>   CreateProcess function). Doing this allows private dynamic-link
>   library (DLL) files associated with a process to be found without
>   adding the process's installed directory to the PATH environment
>   variable. If a relative path is specified, the entire relative path is
>   appended to every token in the DLL search path list. To load a module
>   from a relative path without searching any other path, use
>   GetFullPathName to get a nonrelative path and call LoadLibrary with
>   the nonrelative path. For more information on the DLL search order,
>   see Dynamic-Link Library Search Order.

Comment: Thanks, @AlexanderVX! As I see the only way is to add `c:/etc` into PATH variable since both dlls are not mine and I don't know how they are loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing prevents you from explicitly preloading the libraries that `lib.dll` depends on. Once pre-loaded, they're ready for use by any library that you'll subsequently open. After all, you know where they are so it's a simple matter to iterate them and attempt to load them. Due to possible dependencies between these libraries, you have to keep loading them until there's no more progress:

```
   QString path;
   QSet<QString> libraries;
   QDirIterator it{path, {"*.dll"}};
   while (it.hasNext())
     libraries << it.next();
   bool progress = true;
   while (progress) {
     progress = false;
     for (auto i = libraries.begin(); i != libraries.end();) {
       QLibrary lib{*i};
       if (lib.load()) {
         progress = true;
         i = libraries.erase(i);
       } else
         ++i;
      }
   }
```

It's either that or to use a PE library of your choice to build the dependency tree yourself and only open the necessary libraries, in dependency order.

Side note: you don't own `C:\Windows` and you should never write anything there (nor in any subfolder) in any sort of a modern installer.